# Can't setup separate database for tests - Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, lumen

I'm writing RESTful API in Lumen, and I need to write tests, but I don't want to use the same database, because on tests I need to mock data. 
I run into bunch of troubles while trying to setup separate database where tests will be executed.

I think I've setup it, but problem is, when I run `phpunit`, I got error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or
>   view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exists (SQL:
>   create table 'migrations' ('id' int unsigned not null auto_increment
>   primary key, 'migration' varchar(255) not null, 'batch' int not null)
>   default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci).

So, it migrate just default, production database, not one for testing.

This is what I do:

#### In my_app/config/database.php

```
return [

    'default' => env('DB_DEFAULT', 'mysql'),
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'my_app'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'human_resources_testing' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('TEST_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('TEST_DB_DATABASE', 'my_app_testing'),
            'username'  => env('TEST_DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('TEST_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```

#### In phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="my_app_testing"/>

    </php>
</phpunit>
```

#### .env.testing

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=my_app_secret_key
APP_URL=http://my_app.dev/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
TEST_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
TEST_DB_PORT=3306
TEST_DB_DATABASE=my_app_testing
TEST_DB_USERNAME=root
TEST_DB_PASSWORD=
```

#### In TestCase

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use \Laravel\Lumen\Testing;
use \Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
//        putenv('DB_CONNECTION=sqlite_testing');

        $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

//        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();
//        $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();

        $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->handle(
//            new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput('migrate:install'),
            new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput('migrate'),
            new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput);

        return $app;
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
//        Artisan::call('migrate:install');
//        Artisan::call('migrate');
//        Artisan::call('db:seed');
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
        parent::tearDown();
    }    
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41192295/4881811) !!

Comment: @Maraboc Well, when i try to run tests, i got `Error: Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::loadEnvironmentFrom()`. Also, in my case, what needs to be at `if (config('database.default') == 'sqlite')` ?

Comment: Sorry this answer is just for laravel not lumen applications :p

Comment: No problem, it will be useful for others. Just edit your answer, note that it's for Laravel.

Comment: `DB_CONNECTION`? Don't you mean `DB_DEFAULT`?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to rename the `.env` file.

You need to modify the `phpunit.xml` as you're doing, but don't modify the name of the connection but the name of the database. For example

```
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="my_app_testing"/>
```

What you're doing here is using your normal connection, but specifying a different database. That's because you can define your connection on models, for example

```
public class Car extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_cars';
}
```

And that will use the other connection. If you're defining that field in your models, changing your env `DB_CONNECTION` will do nothing. Instead, you're changing the database that connection will use.

Comment: Hey @Lloople, thanks for the reply! I have both of `env` files, `.env` and `.env.testing`. So i don't need both right?  

Hehe i have changed it to `my_app` because i need to hide details, i'm not allowed to share any detail, sorry :(

Comment: Yeah that's totally fine. You don't need the `.env.testing` file, you app will load `.env` anyways, and then `phpunit.xml` will overwrite the properties you defined there. You need to make sure that the `<env name="DB_CONNECTION"` contains an existing `database.php` connection

Comment: Ok. Should `DB_CONNECTION` contains test database name, or? How about `APP_ENV`?

Comment: `DB_CONNECTION` should contain the name of your connection, which is defined as a key in `database.php`, whic is `human_resources_testing`

Comment: Well, i've tried that, and it work on some way. But, it resets my main database, not testing.

Comment: That's because it's not changing the connection properly. I'll update the answer to explain it better.

Comment: Good. Thank you! :)

Comment: I've tested it, and got `human_resources_testing`. Looks like it's working now, but it still reset main database...

Comment: Oh wait, I know where the problem is, I'll update the entire question

Comment: Hey @Lloople thanks for the replies. And thanks for the tips about `$connection` in model, but i don't have different connections defined in models if you mean on that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I chose to use DatabaseTransactions (trait), that has my main goal, not changing data in my database.

I hope that can be useful.

[Documentation Lumen Test](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing)